# How do we separate a complex matrix into real and imaginary matrices?

Tags: complex

If we have a complex matrix C, how do we separate it into two matrices as C=A+iB, where A and B are real matrices?

Comment: For example: `(cmat = RandomComplex[{-4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I}, {5, 5}]) // MatrixForm`, you can use `MatrixForm /@ {Re[cmat], Im[cmat]}`.

Comment: If you have a matrix with symbolic entries, then please load a concrete example. Symbols with an initial uppercase letter are reserved.

Comment: try `{mata,matb} = Through[{Re, Im}@matc ]`?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use `ReIm`:

```
reim = Table[Map[#[[All, i]] &, ReIm[cmat], {1}], {i, #}] & @@ {2}
MatrixForm/@reim
```

[image]

As Lukas Lang suggests, in compact form it's as follows:

```
Transpose[ReIm[cmat], {2,3,1}]
```

Comment: Quite a bit shorter: `Transpose[ReIm[cmat], {2,3,1}]`

Comment: (+1) Thanks, Lukas! :-)

Comment: What is {2,3,1} here?